# My Laptop is not detecting Bootable USB for dual boot ubuntu 18.04 along side windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

Laptop Model - Asus Vivobook s14, 256GB SSD + 1TB HDD i7- 8th gen, Nvidia Mx150, Windows 10.
I'm trying to dual boot my device with Ubuntu 18.04LTS, I partitioned 100gb in my HDD. but the bootable Pendrive is not detected. I tried with the same with my old laptop which detects the USB for boot. I disabled secure boot, fast boot, Intel RST. I don't know where the issue lies.
[Rufus MBR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj32Z.png) 
[MS Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yP4O.png)

Comment: What tool did you use to make your installer USB? Try **Etcher**, if that does not work, try **Rufus** UEFI: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278772/unable-to-access-ubuntu-from-uefi/1278841#1278841

Comment: I tried both Etcher and Rufus. And Rufus is not giving me an option to change the partition scheme. It is fixed at MBR.

Comment: What do you see when you select `Partition scheme` as in the image below? `Target system` should change automatically when 
GPT is selected. F8 should allow changing the CSM / UEFI mode when booting. Turn off Secure Boot. Confirm Windows is also booting UEFI.

Comment: Secure Boot is disabled as I mentioned in the question. Partition Scheme is Fixed at MBR I'm Unable to change it to GPT. Windows is booting in UEFI mode. I tried updating BIOS which looks like it is in Legacy Mode but it says it is already in the Recent Version. I Still cant find the problem.I attached Rufus and MSInfo images in the question, I still can't boot through USB.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you select quick format? Have you seen this: https://www.infofuge.com/asus-vivobook-s14-s406ua-boot-from-usb/

Comment: Quick format doesn't help. I also tried with older versions of Rufus, but no use. I can't change the partition scheme using any method.

Comment: Have you tried making the USB as UEFI using your old computer, or another computer that will allow the GPT scheme in Rufus? Have you tried 20.04?

Comment: I did as you said, made it GPT and UEFI, but still, it doesn't recognize the USB.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you mean by "doesn't detect pendrive"?  E.g., does it not appear in the list of bootable devices in the BIOS menu?  If you doubt the pendrive can be detected, try making it a Recovery Drive for Windows (you can do that from inside Windows) and then try to boot with it.  If it works, then it is obviously not a problem with the pendrive.  Some BIOS systems are tricky with secure boot - they require a supervisor password to be set before they REALLY allow secure boot to be turned off.  I think that may be deliberate "security through obfuscation".

Comment: Pendrive doesn't show up in the list of bootable devices. The Pendrive is absolutely fine because I can boot it on my older laptop. Secure Boot is turned off along with fast boot. but BIOS doesnt show the option of CSM.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I installed Ubuntu after trying for very long time.

1. I changed the partition scheme to GPT in rufus.
2. I enabled mass storage in bios.
3. I tried downloading the ubuntu image again.

I don't know which of the following helped, but I was able to install ubuntu and now its running smoothly. Thank you everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

### Rufus Settings for UEFI Only Ubuntu Install

In BIOS select `Security` tab then press the `Secure Boot Control` button and `Disable`. Select the `Save & Exit` tab, then `Generic USB Flash Disk 0.00`

Note **Partition scheme** and **Target system** for UEFI only install.

[image]