# Application for creating Bootable pen drive that supports in UEFI mode

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

I want to change the operating system from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to POP! OS .My computer is in UEFI mode. I downloaded the iso file and created the bootable pen drive  using balenaEtcher but it is creating in Legacy mode. Is there any application for Linux to create a bootable pen drive in UEFI mode because i do not want to change the boot order of computer to Legacy mode.

Comment: You should have an option to boot the Etcher pen drive in UEFI mode. Try pressin F9 or F12, etc. If you have access to a Windows computer, Rufus will make a UEFI only pendrive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278772/unable-to-access-ubuntu-from-uefi/1278841#1278841

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'd use Startup Disk Creator, it's included with every Ubuntu release and is generally more user friendly and reliable.

Make sure the iso is indeed meant for UEFI, sometimes they will be UEFI/BIOS specific.

Gotta ask, though, why are you installing Pop when you're already running Ubuntu?

It'd be a lot easier just to configure the Pop apt repo and update your current OS, since Pop IS Ubuntu with window dressing.

You can install any of Pop's software from their apt repo:
https://apt.pop-os.org/

They have all those packages and more on their GitHub profile:
https://github.com/pop-os

Good luck!