# Ubuntu drive not listed in UEFI setup

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, uefi

I have been researching this problem for a while now, so I hope this isn't a duplicate.

I am running two SSDs on my system. One for Windows 10, one for Linux.
After installing Ubuntu 20.04 on the Linux SSD (replacing the previous debian installation), the device is no longer listed as an UEFI device in the EFI setup utility. I am not able to set this device as the primary boot option.
**However**, when I use the boot menu (F11). The drive is listed. I can select it and Grub starts correctly. I can also run Win from there.

I did the following:

1. Create a bootable USB drive (according to this: [How to create UEFI-only bootable USB live media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media))
2. Booted the drive in UEFI mode
3. Use custom partitioning. Create a 300MB partition with mount point `/boot/efi` and flag `boot`

Things I have tried:

1. Add the `ESP` flag after installing using gparted
2. Reinstall having `secure boot` turned off
3. Reinstall using `UEFI + Legacy` mode
4. I was checking out the `boot-repair` tool. This lists that the EFI partition is present
5. The output of `efibootmgr -v` is as follows:

```
root@lubuntu:/home/lubuntu# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0005                                                                                                                                                                            
Timeout: 1 seconds                                                                                                                                                                           
BootOrder: 0001,0000,0003,0005,0004                                                                                                                                                          
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,45163052-5fdf-4174-a84b-9383a3e67e8b,0x109000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...M................                                                                                                             
Boot0001* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)/VenHw(5ce8128b-2cec-40f0-8372-80640e3dc858,0200)..GO..NO..........S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .8.5.0. .E.V.O. .2.5.0.G.B...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.2.S.6.R.X.N.J.0.0.7.9.5.9.7. .A. . . . ........BO..NO..........S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .8.5.0. .E.V.O. .2.5.0.G.B...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.2.S.6.R.X.N.J.1.1.1.6.7.8.4. .N. . . . ........BO..NO..........S.T.2.0.0.0.D.M.0.0.8.-.2.F.R.1.0.2...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . . . . . . . .F.Z.1.L.7.L.L.Y........BO..NO..........S.T.2.0.0.0.D.M.0.0.6.-.2.D.M.1.6.4...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . . . . . . . .4.Z.7.Z.V.W.G.D........BO                                                            
Boot0003* ubuntu        HD(1,GPT,971a9558-bfc4-644a-8ad3-274e7f78c4ae,0x800,0x96000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)                                                                           
Boot0004* USB KEY       BBS(HD,,0x0)/VenHw(5ce8128b-2cec-40f0-8372-80640e3dc858,0b00)..GO..NO..........S.a.n.D.i.s.k...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.............................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.4.C.5.3.0.0.0.0.2.0.0.1.2.3.1.1.8.2.9.5........BO                                                                                                                           
Boot0005* UEFI: SanDisk, Partition 1    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x0,0x800,0x3947800)..BO
```

I am really quite stumped by this. Advice is greatly appreciated.

The mainboard I am using is a MSI B350 PC Mate

Answer (score 0):

If you using any gnome based distro (like Ubuntu) create bootable usb drive using **Startup Disk Creator** or if you are using Windows try **Rufus** to create bootable usb and try to install Ubuntu again.

Comment: I created another bootable USB drive using Rufus. The outcome is unfortunately still the same.
I feel I must be missing out on something obvious :(

Comment: How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is how it installs. You should normally have two entries for booting live installer. But Rufus only converts ISO to either UEFI or BIOS/Legacy/CSM, so you have to choose correctly in Rufus first and then only will have UEFI boot option. Rufus screen to select UEFI (non CSM) installer.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278772/unable-to-access-ubuntu-from-uefi

Comment: I suggest that you use balenaEtcher instead of rufus.  It is a simple application that will create bootable installation media from the ISO that is capable of being booted UEFI or compatibility/BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after almost an entire day of investigating this. I solved the problem by

1. Disabling fast boot
2. Installing the latest BIOS

Honestly, I am not quite sure which of those did do the trick, but it works now