# Ubuntu installation on second drive HDD and keeping windows on NMVe

Tags: dual-boot, software-installation

I have a DELL G5 5590 laptop comes with tow different storage technology.
250 Gb NVMe and 1Tb HDD
I want to use a partition of my HDD to install   Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on it.

I have a Windows 10 version preinstalled on a 256 NVMe drive. i want to keep windows and install ubuntu both with dual boot menu.
but I don't know if it's possible!
I don't want to lose my preinstalled version of Windows.
I don't know what config/parameter used when burning ubuntu image on my USB memory stick.
The bios shows EUFI
Which one should I use?
Also MBR or GPT ?
Thank you

Comment: You only want UEFI & gpt. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296257/installing-lubuntu-20-04-with-gpt-and-efi &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & Dell typically need UEFI update & SSD firmware update. And drives changed to AHCI after you add AHCI driver into Windows. https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347 How to Install Ubuntu Linux on your Dell PC 
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en

Comment: After many research I found that if I change to AHCI I will lose my windows at 99.9% even the volume will not be recognized anymore. So redefine the drive again and assign C: by hand ... I tried to change it but the bios itself warn me that I will lose the drive and the system. Is that true ?

Comment: Never heard that any real issues with Windows in AHCI mode. I have one Windows system just to watch TV and it works fine with AHCI. But you have to add the AHCI drivers into Windows first.