# UEFI Ubuntu option has been removed after changing modes

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I had a dual boot installation with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. One day I got a screen **No boot device found** and I couldn't enter neither of the OS installed on my laptop. So after reading ways to solve this problem, I decided to switch the UEFI mode to Legacy mode. This way I was able to access the Windows OS only.

However, then I changed back again to the UEFI mode, but unfortunately there was no ubuntu option anymore, and the disk partitions dedicated to Ubuntu were not visible anymore in Windows OS file manager, although I could see the partitions inside the Windows 10 disk configurator app.

Any advice how can I restore the ubuntu as an UEFI option if possible? Or save the partition at least?

Comment: If you have UEFI system & UEFI installs never use legacy. Never change settings in UEFI and never choose to boot live installer in old BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode. Make sure live installer is created in UEFI boot mode. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296257/installing-lubuntu-20-04-with-gpt-and-efi Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: "*is problem, I decided to switch the UEFI mode to Legacy mode*" - What **exactly** did you do here?  Have you already tried os-prober and boot-repair?  UEFI/BIOS mode is chosen at system installation. You need to be consistent with your use of these with all installed operating systems. If one OS was installed in UEFI mode and the other in BIOS/compatibility, this problem will not go away easily until you reinstall the operating system(s) so they are consistent