# Create Ubuntu usb drive on GPT

Tags: usb, gpt, mbr

I'm trying to make a USB with ubuntu on it be bootable from Macs. I have made a working usb drive partitioned MBR, it boots on my laptop but not on Macs. I predict that the problem is that the usb drive is mbr. Googling on how to change the partition to gpt I found out that usb drives cant to become gpt partitioned. If anyone knows how to make it gpt, It would be amazing.

My current solution is to buy soled state usb drives, but they're expensive and I need multiple drives that run on mac.

Comment: Did this article help you?  https://www.vanstechelman.eu/content/creating-an-uefi-bootable-linux-usb-stick

Comment: More likely the difference is a UEFI vs legacy boot setup.  How did you set up the USB, and how does your MAC boot now?

Comment: I have been partitioning USB flash drives as gpt for almost 10 years. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu  As I understand it, you need to have gpt with an ESP - efi system partition and set for UEFI boot.

Comment: Rufus for UEFI only install: https://askubuntu.com/a/1278841/43926