# Unable to Install Ubuntu 18.04 from Bootable USB onto Windows 10 Dell computer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb, windows

I have a Dell G5 5505 Laptop (AMD Ryzen 9 4900H 8-Core, 64GB RAM, 1TB PCIe SSD, 15.6" Full HD (1920x1080), AMD RX 5600M, Wifi, Bluetooth, Webcam, 1xUSB 3.2, 1xHDMI, Win 10 Home) which comes with Windows 10, but I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 using a bootable USB. I created the bootable USB using Rufus as described in this tutorial (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview). Then I insert the USB stick into the computer, access the boot options by holding F12, and it brings me to the GRUB screen with the options to "try Ubuntu before installing", "Install Ubuntu", etc. etc. If I select "try Ubuntu before installing" or "Install Ubuntu" the screen goes black, and then it gives me these 3 errors:

ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/dswload2-163)

ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-221)

pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.

Then after maybe 10ish seconds the screen goes black and the laptop reboots back into the Windows login screen. I haven't been able to get to the Ubuntu login/installation screen.

I have Secure Boot disabled and I have Fast Boot set to "minimal." The BIOS mode listed is "UEFI". USB Emulation is enabled and USB Wake Support is disabled.

What can I do to get to the Ubuntu installation screen? I have been a lifelong Windows user and have zero experience trying to install or use Ubuntu. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I do not understand the instructions saying to use BIOS & MBR. New systems are UEFI with gpt partitioning. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278772/unable-to-access-ubuntu-from-uefi Also Dell typically requires you to install AHCI drivers into WIndows & turn off RAID/Intel RST in UEFI settings. Also: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2454083&page=2&p=14002765#post14002765 Dell - All
https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-is/sln298524/how-to-use-and-troubleshoot-the-inspiron-17-5759?lang=en&ref=topsolutions#Resetting_System_Setup

Comment: `pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter` seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62827591/ .

Comment: @user535733 Yes I saw that article as well! However I don't know how to follow its directions for "editing the GRUB file at etc/default/grub"; I don't see any folder named "etc" in the bootable USB that I made?

Comment: Correct. You cannot modify the bootable USB. It's read-only. Were this an *already installed* system, that would be the answer. Since I'm not an expert on the installer's GRUB, the comment was intended to help somebody who is such an expert when they come along.

Comment: With a Rufus install you can just edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg from windows using notepad.