# How boot EFI rather than from MBR

Tags: system-installation, uefi, bootloader, grub-efi

I was forced to reinstall Ubuntu, wiping out a lot of engineering programs and data because a Windows-10 update deleted and overwrote my Xubuntu partition. Computer was duel boot: Windows-10, XUbuntu 20.04. Nothing (not Windows nor Ubuntu) would boot.

I could only use a "live CD" which really isn't live but apparently the name for the Ubuntu boot/install DVD?

I was told that this was because I installed the bootloader on my MBR rather than by using GPT with UEFI.

Since I have to do a completely new install, how do I install it GPT/ UEFI rather than by MBR? It seems that MBR is the default.

Comment: MBR repair isn't that hard, it should be fully recoverable, look for super grub disk as a first step.   Converting from MBR to EFI without reinstalling is possible but not easy for both operating systems.  If you are going to reinstall, the first step is to enable efi boot in your bios and boot efi enabled OS install media.

Comment: In order to install and use UEFI operating systems, you need the drive to be formatted with a GPT partition scheme and you need to boot the installation media in UEFI mode (not BIOS/MBR/compatibility)

Comment: Thanks. MBR repair isn't hard for an experienced Linux tech but I've spent 2 weeks on it using Gparted, gpart, and TestDisk and haven't been able to do it.  Thus I did a reinstall of Ubuntu 20.04 but now have the famous "no keyboard" problem.  Apparently the no keyboard problem is a bug: many keyboards (US type) simply don't work with Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks Nmath.  I've noticed a UEFI option in boot menu and will reformat for this. Do I just need to reformat the EXT4 partition,  I guess it's the whole drive tho?

Comment: GPT is a disk partitioning scheme that affects the whole disk.

Comment: If drive is MBR, you need to first convert to gpt. But this erases drive and Windows has to also be installed in UEFI boot mode. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions use swap file so swap partition optional:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation With gparted select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting.

Comment: To install in UEFI mode you need to boot the installer in UEFI mode, here is how to guarantee Rufus boots and installs Ubuntu in UEFI mode: https://askubuntu.com/a/1278841/43926

Comment: Enabled UEFI in bios and now computer has the famous "no keyboard" issue.  Apparently from everything I've learned this is a non-recoverable error.  Since my motherboard's old I plan to fix this by installing a new motherboard.