# How do u acess grub menu to boot into windows 10?

Tags: grub2, windows-10

I download Unbuntu and I’m having trouble to boot into Windows 10, my main c drive I need help please

Comment: What trouble are you having?  You should see a grub menu, with ubuntu first, and Windows a few lines lower.  Is your Windows installation UEFI or legacy -- grub must be installed in the same mode to boot Windows.  What instructions did you follow?  More information will help us make reasonable suggestions.

Comment: You can set up Rufus to only boot and install in UEFI mode. once both Windows and Ubuntu are booting in the same mode Windows should boot from the Ubuntu GRUB menu. see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1278841/43926

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things that might have happened.

It's possible that you've accidentally deleted the Windows partition when you installed Ubuntu. Open up `gparted` and see if you can still see the Windows partitions (usually you'll see at least one big NTFS partition). If you can't see them there, then check whether the current Ubuntu install is where you would have expected Windows to be (i.e. if you only have one hard drive and it has Ubuntu taking up all the space, then you've probably installed Ubuntu over the top of Windows).

If you can see the Windows partitions, then it's also possible that it's only a boot-loader issue. Usually when Ubuntu installs, it looks for other operating systems and includes them in the boot menu. If this hasn't worked, the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) application can help. You can install and run it using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

The tool is pretty self explanatory, but the link I provided has more information. After running `boot-repair` hopefully you'll be able to boot back into Windows.

Answer (score -1):

I believe Ubuntu overwrites Windows boot loader.Look up fix master boot record MBR for windows 10. You will need a usb drive with Windows 10. Or use the ubuntu Boot-Repair software. Then in the ubuntu terminal use "os-prober" to find windows and "nano /etc/default/grub" if you want to change timeout of grub from 5 to 10. Apply changes with "sudo update-grub".

Link for fixing windows 10 master boot record. https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/windows-mbr-fix.html

Comment: Windows 10 from the manufacturer has been installed in UEFI mode for about 10 years, so likely there is no MBR in the picture.  Only updates from Win 7 would be legacy with an MBR.